# How to maintain multiple versions of an application?

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, software-design

this is  basically an opinion based question but I need some guidance regarding how to approach versioning of features of an existing application.

We have both android and ios apps for an application and the api is written in laravel. Now we are upgrading some features which have effects on old features. For example, in the app you can create groups and select groups interest. Now we want to allow multiple interests for a group. So from one to one relation we are changing to one to many which changes the db structure. So how do I handle the old groups that has been created with one interest? Even if I separate code for version 2, how do I separate the database? How do you generally handle situations like that? I am not looking for exact solution but an general idea about approaching this. Thanks.

Comment: _this is basically an opinion based question_ you are inviting close votes for offtopic here..

Comment: Letting us know that you know that the question is off topic doesn't make it on topic. It actually makes it slightly worse.

Comment: I don't think this is an off-topic question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a code issue as much as it sounds like a data migration issue.

If I understand you correctly, you had a one-to-one relationship between groups and interests (I'm guessing it might even have been in one table) and your new structure now has a one-to-many relationship.  My approach would be to migrate the old data to the new structure.  Sure, this will mean that for existing groups, the "many" side of the relationship will only have one record, but there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Off topic questions shouldn't be answered since it kind of validate sit. The OP and/or other people seeing the question later might then continue asking off topic questions, since the still get answers.